# Java : Creating an array from an for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I have a list of files in a array

```
String[] myStringArray = {"C:\file1.txt","C:\file2.txt","C:\file3.txt"};
```

For which I'm running  a for loop to execute a command to get a value

```
for (String extpath: myStringArray ) {
command to get the metadata
}
```

Output:
**modified
modified
unmodified**

I'm able to get the above working. Now I need to compare each element of the output and see of they are same are different.

Should that again be created as a array and then be compared? any pointers please on the easiest approach

Comment: No need. You can just store the previous value in a variable and check with current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to store the output of each iteration of the loop in an array, you'll need a regular for loop, since you'll need the index of the array (unless you add a local counter variable).

```
String[] output = new String[myStringArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++) {
    String extpath = myStringArray[i];
    output[i] = command to get the metadata
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `Map<String, Boolean>` which you update as you go along. The key in this case, would be the name of the file while the value would be if the file has been modified or not, so basically:

```
Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
...
for (String extpath: myStringArray ) {
    boolean result = ...
    if(map.get(extPath) == result) {
        //What to do if they are the same
    }
    else {
        //What to do if they are different
    }
    map.get(i) = result; //Update the map
}
```

The code above should allow you to do what you are after with just 1 pass.